New to Power Automate and having trouble with JSON Objects/Arrays
I'm going to preface this question by saying I am new to Microsoft Power Automate and I am excited to learn what it can really do.
So... I'm working on a Power Automate flow that grabs information from a connection that uses an API call that generates a JSON object, which is a nested array of JSON objects. Here's the beginning of the output I get when I use that action:
{
  "count": 790,
  "page": 1,
  "results": {
    "rows": [
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "name": "user_id",
            "value": "12345678"
          },
          {
            "name": "givenName",
            "value": "George"
          },
          {
            "name": "surname",
            "value": "Washington"
          },
          {
            "name": "year",
            "value": "1776"
          },
          {
            "name": "role",
            "value": "Incoming Student"
          }
        ]
      }
}


Here's what I have so far:
Power Automate Flow
So what I'm looking to do in Power Automate is to get the values of user_id, givenName, surname, year, and role for each person out and get them into a CSV or table. For the life of me I can't figure out how to make Power Automate do this, despite reading the various documentation and references available. It just... doens't work the way I hoped it would.
Would anyone on here be willing and able to give me some much-needed guidance? I thank you all in advance for your expertise and your help!
—Samad
I tried using the Data Operations functions like Select and Filter Array but I can't seem to suss out the data I need.
